# form onsubmit doesnt work properly

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a login form im making, and I want to test if the inputs are empty or not.
I don't get an error, but when i submit it just ignores the onsubmit.
help?

this is my form:

```
 <form onsubmit="return ifEmpty();" action="login1.php" method="post" id="loginform" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                    <div style="vertical-align: top;" dir="rtl">
                        <label dir="rtl" class="labels">שם משתמש/אימייל</label>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <input name="unameemail" id="username" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: block;vertical-align:top;" dir="rtl">
                        <br>
                        <label dir="rtl" class="labels">סיסמה</label>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <input name="password" id="passwordin" type="password">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <input class="btn" type="submit" name="submitone" onclick="" value="login">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

and my js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function ifEmpty() {

                if (document.getElementById("username") == "") {

                    document.getElementById("username").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("username").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("username").className += " invalidform";
                    return false;
                } else if (document.getElementById("passwordin") == "") {
                    document.getElementById("username").style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    document.getElementById("username").style.color = "black";
                    document.getElementById("password").style.backgroundColor = "red";
                    document.getElementById("password").style.color = "white";
                    document.getElementById("password").className += " invalidform";
                    return false;
                }

            }

        </script>
```

Comment: You are comparing DOM elements to strings, that does not make sense. You need to access the `value` property of the input elements.

Comment: OHHH yes thank you i forgot......

Comment: that was a silly mistake :D

Comment: post an answer so I can "declare" it as the official answer

Comment: So it didn't ignore onsubmit, it just errored out in it.

Comment: yea I thought it ignored onsubmit. mb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if (document.getElementById("username") == "") {

You are comparing DOM elements to strings here ;-)

You need to access the value property of the input elements.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (document.getElementById("username") == "") {
```

to this:

```
if (document.getElementById("username").value == "") {
```